# Google script app - create trigger at specific date and time by script

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, triggers

I need to create a trigger running at a specific date and time (format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM) with google script.
As result of my script, trigger is listed into "Trigger Panel" and scheduled at right date time but not starts at all.
If I code manually the trigger, with same data time, it starts when due.

Here are examples of my tests:

```
function TriggerTest()
{   
 var newDate   = new Date().setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes() + 1440)  //next day to start trigger
 var newYYYY   = new Date(newDate).getFullYear();     
 var newMM     = new Date(newDate).getMonth();       
 var newDD     = new Date(newDate).getDate();       
 var newHH     = 06;       //Hour start trigger
 var newMI     = 50;       //Minute start trigger

 //Example 1 - date, time (using valueOf)
 var strTimerTrigger = new Date(newYYYY,newMM,newDD,newHH,newMI,00,000000).valueOf();
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("DummyTrigger").timeBased().at(new Date(strTimerTrigger)).create();

//Example 2 - date, time (using valueOf)
var strTimerTrigger = new Date(newYYYY,newMM,newDD,newHH,newMI).valueOf();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("DummyTrigger").timeBased().at(new Date(strTimerTrigger)).create();

//Example 3 - date, time (using parameters)
ScriptApp.newTrigger("DummyTrigger").timeBased().at(new Date(newYYYY, newMM, newDD, 
 13, 30)).create();

//Example 4 - date, time (using hard code)
ScriptApp.newTrigger("DummyTrigger").timeBased().at(new Date(2022, 03, 12, 13, 50)).create();

//Example 5 - date, time (using string)
ScriptApp.newTrigger("DummyTrigger").timeBased().at("2022-04-12 14:00").create();

//Example 6 - 
const dummy   = new Date(2022, 03, 12, 14, 15);
ScriptApp.newTrigger("DummyTrigger").timeBased().at(new Date(dummy)).create();

//Example 7
ScriptApp.newTrigger("DummyTrigger").timeBased().at((dummy)).create();
```

}

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot in advance!!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLiJd.png)

Comment: check if timezone in project manifest is set to the same as your local timezone https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests

Comment: Thanks alot! I've modified project manifest TimeZone Value from America/New_York to Europe/Rome. Now everything it's fine. Great! Davide

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder

at date function will run at midnight on that date, it will not allow to specify the time.

The only option for time is to use

```
// Creates a trigger that runs 10 minutes later
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .after(10 * 60 * 1000)
  .create();
```

You can modify the time to fit your needs.